# How to set locale in ocaml?

Tags: localization, ocaml, curses

I'm interested in changing `LC_ALL` in an ocaml program. The equivalent C function would be `setlocale(LC_ALL, "my_new_locale");`. How would one do this in ocaml?

Comment: You can set an environment variable with `Unix.putenv`. Not sure what `setlocale` does beyond that.

Comment: Some context, might be useful: I'm using the ocaml ncurses lib, but unicode characters fail to appear. I wrote up a test ncurses program in C and found that unicode characters also did not work. 

After digging I found out that adding `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` before `initscr();` fixes the issue in C, so I'm attempting to port that fix to ocaml.

Comment: I believe setting locale is deeper than a wrapper around an env variable change, but I'm not sure either.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), but maybe just try? And if that doesn't work, perhaps try setting `LC_ALL` before running the program? The initial locale has to come from the environment somewhere, and that's usually where.

Comment: This fits exactly with the XY problem view, thanks for sharing that. In retrospect I should've started with the ocaml ncurses question.

Comment: As for testing the `LC_ALL` solution, I did so (setting the env variable from command line), and I can confirm the environment variable change. It didn't fix the ncurses problem. But if localization reduces to env variables set for a program, then this would solve the posted question

Comment: There might be other problems, with the input rather than the output, for example. Which is why it's an XY problem. If you show a [mcve] of the underlying problem it would be easier to help.

Comment: Sure, it's simply `Curses.addstr "あ"`, ignoring the [functions needed to setup ncurses](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/helloworld.html). `addstr("あ");` works in C.

Comment: You may want to try using a Unicode escape sequence instead. I'm not sure when the parser started supporting Unicode directly in string literals. There may also be file encoding issues. Using an escape sequence should avoid both those problems. Locale is otherwise not a property of the language, but of the API. Worst case, you may have to bind (or find a binding) to `setlocale`.

Comment: `Printf.printf "あ\u{3042}"` in ocaml 5.1.1 prints "ああ", so the language has support for directly putting unicode characters in strings. As for the library, `Curses.addstr "\u{3042}"` does not work.